# Simple function is not working as I expected

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have very simple function, I just want to update the `salary` column based on a passed parameter. I know I can do it by procedure but what is wrong with this code, can anyone explain me please.

Table and data structure:

```
create table emp_test  (emp_id number,  salary number);
insert into emp_test values (10,750);
insert into emp_test values (11,850);
insert into emp_test values (12,650);
insert into emp_test values (13,950);
insert into emp_test values (14,1750);
insert into emp_test values (15,2750);
```

And the Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
CIS_EXT.UPDATE_EMP_SAL( p_emp_id IN emp_test.emp_id%TYPE )
return NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMP_TEST SET SALARY = SALARY+200
  WHERE  EMP_ID = p_emp_id;
  COMMIT;
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END UPDATE_EMP_SAL ;
```

When I run like below

```
SELECT UPDATE_EMP_SAL(10) FROM DUAL;
```

My output is coming 0. Why?

Comment: The help center has [a section on how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3):

You are hiding the actual error with your `when others` exception handler. [That is almost always a bug](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1155066278457); all you are doing is suppressing useful information, and letting the caller think everything is OK, unless they happen to know to check (and how to interpret) the return value. It is better to not handle the unexpected exception here, and let the caller decide what to do when it sees it. (It's also better to not commit or rollback inside a procedure/function, as it can break the caller's transaction, but that's a separate issue).

If you remove that exception handler you will see that it says:

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
```

The description of that error is:

> *Cause:    DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update
>              cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.
>   *Action:   Ensure that the offending DML operation is not performed or
>              use an autonomous transaction to perform the DML operation within
>              the query or PDML slave.

It's allowed for a function to do DML, though it's generally preferred to only do DML inside a procedure. But if your function does do DML, you can only then call it from PL/SQL:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  rc number;
begin
  rc := UPDATE_EMP_SAL(10);
  dbms_output.put_line(rc);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

1

select * from emp_test where emp_id = 10;

    EMP_ID     SALARY
---------- ----------
        10        950
```

Comment: @Sohel - [To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)